# EnableWebMvc annotation breaks loading of static resources from separate jar

Tags: spring, angular, spring-mvc, spring-boot, angular-cli

I used the guide at https://blog.jdriven.com/2016/12/angular2-spring-boot-getting-started/ to create a webapp utilizing Angular CLI and Spring Boot. With some adjustments, I was able to bundle the backend project into a war with the frontend code included in a jar (which is included in the war's /WEB-INF/lib directory). The webapp loads as expected if the tutorial code is not modified.

Using this project as a template, I attempted to port one of our existing projects. However, when I load the web app, I get a 404 error. I was able to track the problem down to me using the @EnableWebMvc annotation in my configuration class. If this annotation is in use, it seems like the static resources in my front end jar don't load.

This problem continues even when I add the resource location explicitly.

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {     
registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
}
```

I can verify that my index.html is located in the /static directory in my front end jar.
I've been looking at different answers here and adding the resource location should have fixed this issue; clearly there's something else I'm missing here.

I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.3 and deploying to Tomcat. Thanks!

Comment: Adding `@EnableWebMvc` disables a whole lot of autoconfiguration of Spring Boot and yes also for static resource handling. Just remove the annotation.

Comment: I've found that removing the annotation breaks my RestControllers. The GetMappings still work, but my PostMappings start having issues.

Comment: Then you must have configured something specific in your own configuration. Spring Boot, do you extend some of the web configuration classes of Spring MVC?

Comment: Yep, WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.

Comment: Well as long as that is a `@Configuration` that shouldn't be a problem. Maybe you need to ask a different question on why your `@PostMapping` behaves differently (and add code and configuration).

Comment: OK, I've removed the annotation and now I'm getting an org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException. The message states that a required request part is not present. Now, I looked around and this is why I had the EnableWebMvc annotation; this link might explain why I'm getting this exception when I do post requests: http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/spring-enablewebmvc-annotation/.

Comment: That links doesn't explain anything like that, because regardless of the annotation or not you are loading the `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`. Are you deploying the application or are you running it as an embedded container?

Comment: I'm deploying the war onto Tomcat.

Comment: OK, looks like I pretty much sabotaged myself when I was trying to get things working when I first implemented the file upload with the EnableWebMvc annotation. I had created a bean to override the default multipart resolver which did not play well with the default Spring Boot configuration. I removed both and things look good again. Thanks.